# JavaScript countdown sync with servertime

Tags: javascript, c#, webforms, countdown

I need to develop a countdown, which synchronizes with the time on the server.
The job is pretty easy, I have a Form divided in 3 steps, the first step need to be filled and posted in 2 minutes, the last step in two hours.
I have to show the user the countdown but I also need to do this job on the server because we can't rely on the user's local time, we need to secure this countdown with the server time to prevent user's tricks. (we are on iis with asp.net webforms)
I also can't use a database to store time's information, I need to do this with session/cache variables (PM Orders)

any suggestions?

Comment: You need to show what you have written so far, and how it relates to what you want to achieve. At the moment your question is far too vague.

Comment: Store in session start time and always calculate time in requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can send your server time to client and get a difference in client time and server time and save this time difference, and also save the starting time stamp of timer.
You can verify this timer accuracy latter by hitting the server for server time and calculate new difference between client and server time, if it find any discrepancy, correct the timer.